# A formula for homology groups of cartesian product of finitely many spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

By Kunneth Formula, for positive integers $m,n$, if $m\neq n$, then

$$H_p (S^m \times S^n)=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z} & \text{if}\;  p=0,m,n,m+n\\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and if $m= n$, then

$$H_p (S^m \times S^m)=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z} & \text{if}\;  p=0,2m\\ \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}& \text{if}\; p=m \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Is there any specific formula for homology groups of $\prod_{n\in I}(\prod_{r_n}S^n)$, where $\prod_{r_n}S^n$ denotes the product of $r_n$ copies of $S^n$, $I$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and $r_n \in \mathbb{N}$?

What I've tried: I could get the following formula for homology groups of $\prod_{m}S^n$: $$H_p (\prod_{m}S^n)=\begin{cases}{m \choose k} \; \text{copies of}\; \mathbb{Z},& \text{if}\; p=kn\\ 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sure, just keep applying the Kunneth formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Künneth formula, each of the homology groups will be free abelian, so we only need to keep track of the rank. We can keep track of the ranks using some algebra; to start with, the rank of $H_p(S^m)$ is the coefficient of $x^p$ in $1+x^m$. Now use the Künneth formula to prove that the rank of $H_p(S^m \times S^n)$ is the coefficient of $x^p$ in the polynomial $(1+x^m) (1+x^n)$. In general, the rank of $H_p$ in the homology of $\prod_{n_i \in J} S^{n_i}$ is the coefficient of $x^p$ in $\prod (1 + x^{n_i})$. This coefficient is the number of ways of writing $p$ as a sum of some of the $n_i$'s.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer.

Comment: Dear @JohnPalmieri Is there a reference for the above statement? Actually I want to use it in my work and I need a reference for it.

Comment: The "Hilbert polynomial" is the general name for a polynomial used to keep track of dimensions of a graded vector space or the ranks of graded free abelian group. I don't have a specific reference, though.

Comment: Understood. Apreciate your help.